# How to remove checkbox element based from a selected option in a Select element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove a checkbox element when a select option which is identical by text or value is clicked in a SELECT element.
For example, when **option value *College GWA*** is selected, the equivalent CheckBox labeled *College GWA* should be removed.

Select Element:

```
 <select name="target_column" class="select form-control" id="id_target_column">
  <option value="College GWA">College GWA</option>
  <option value="Field Study">Field Study</option>
  <option value="Compre">Compre</option
```

Checkbox Element:

```
 <div id="div_id_features" class="form-group">
   <label for="" class=""> Feature </label>
     <div class="">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feature_manual" id="id_feature_manual_1" value="College GWA" >
            <label class="form-check-label" for="id_feature_manual_1">
             College GWA
            </label>
        
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feature_manual" id="id_feature_manual_2" value="Field Study" >
            <label class="form-check-label" for="id_feature_manual_2">
              Field Study
            </label>
        
        </div>
   
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feature_manual" id="id_feature_manual_3" value="Compre" >
          <label class="form-check-label" for="id_feature_manual_3">
            Compre
          </label>       
         </div>
```

jQuery code:

```
   $("select.target_column").change(function(){
        var selected_col = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

        $("input[name='feature_manual']:contains".join(selected_col)).remove();
    });
```

Comment: `join()` is an array method.... you are trying to use it on strings. This should be throwing an error in your browser dev tools console but you haven't mentioned errors. Also `:contains()` selector  only works on text content, not form controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version is made with the selector you were trying to use `contains` but obviously requires that the `select` values are not contained in multiple labels.
Certainly charlietfl's solution is more solid.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#id_target_column").change(function() {
    
    var selected_col = $(this).val();
    $("input[name='feature_manual']~label:contains('" + selected_col + "')").parent().remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="target_column" class="select form-control" id="id_target_column">
  <option value="College GWA">College GWA</option>
  <option value="Field Study">Field Study</option>
  <option value="Compre">Compre</option>
</select>
<br>
  Checkbox Element:

  <div id="div_id_features" class="form-group">
    <label for="" class=""> Feature </label>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feature_manual" id="id_feature_manual_1" value="College GWA">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="id_feature_manual_1">
             College GWA
            </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feature_manual" id="id_feature_manual_2" value="Field Study">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="id_feature_manual_2">
              Field Study
            </label>

    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feature_manual" id="id_feature_manual_3" value="Compre">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="id_feature_manual_3">
            Compre
          </label>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` since `:contains()` is only for text content and does not work with form control values.

Alternatively you could loop over all the checkboxes using `each`

```js
$('#id_target_column').change(function() {
  var selVal = $(this).val()
  $("input[name='feature_manual']").filter(function() {
    var checkVal = this.value;
    return checkVal === selVal;
  }).parent().remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="target_column" class="select form-control" id="id_target_column">
  <option value="College GWA">College GWA</option>
  <option value="Field Study">Field Study</option>
  <option value="Compre">Compre</option>

</select>
<div id="div_id_features" class="form-group">
  <label for="" class=""> Feature </label>
  <div class="">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feature_manual" id="id_feature_manual_1" value="College GWA">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="id_feature_manual_1">
             College GWA
            </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feature_manual" id="id_feature_manual_2" value="Field Study">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="id_feature_manual_2">
              Field Study
            </label>

    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feature_manual" id="id_feature_manual_3" value="Compre">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="id_feature_manual_3">
            Compre
          </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use template literals to find the right selector. First, in your select element, `target_column` is not a class, so it'd be easier to use its id.
Since the value attr in the checkbox is the same as the option, you could do this:

```
$("#id_target_column").change(function(){

  var selected_col = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  const checkbox_selector = `input[value="${selected_col}"]`
  $(checkbox_selector).parent().remove();

});
```

and remove the parent, so the label gets removed too.